# Как работает конструкция (в описании) в php?

Tags: php

```
$funk = array(new ORMe(), 'Read'); // Создали массив

$funk(Review::TABLE, $id) // ВОТ ЭТО НЕПОНЯТНО $переменная(параметры метода Read)
```

В классе ORMe есть метод `Read`:

```
public function Read($table, $id = null, $page = null, $limit = null)
{
    $newId = $id ? $id : null;
    $test = array(new Crud(), 'Read');
    return $test($table, $this->getColumns($table), $newId, $page, $limit);
}
```

Каким образом "непонятная" конструкция его вызвала?
Я имею в виду, что мы создали массив `$func` с двумя элементами в первом хранится объект ORMe, а во-втором просто строка с названием метода класса ORMe, как это работает?
Подскажите пожалуйста. В самом методе `Read` используется такой же трюк с классом `Crud` и его методом `Read`.

Answer (score 1):

Это способ свернуть функцию вызова: массив с классом в нулевой позиции и названием метода в первой.

Т. е. `$a = [new Crud(), 'Read']; $a();` то же, что и `(new Crud())->Read()`.
Зачем - передать функцию куда-то, например, без лишних затрат.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если ответ Вас устроил, то примите его (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

На ваш вопрос отвечает документация:

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php

> С версии PHP 5.4.0, можно вызывать callable-функцию, помещенную в
>   переменную.
>
> Пример #4 Сallable-фукнции

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    static function bar()
    {
        echo "bar\n";
    }
    function baz()
    {
        echo "baz\n";
    }
}

$func = array("Foo", "bar");
$func(); // выведет "bar"
$func = array(new Foo, "baz");
$func(); // выведет "baz"
$func = "Foo::bar";
$func(); // выведет "bar" в PHP 7.0.0 и выше; в предыдущих версиях это приведет к фатальной ошибке
?>
```

По факту, в такой конструкции вы первым элементом передаете класс, а последующими: методы либо переменные.

Comment: Большое спасибо)